# Get parameters from Object

Tags: java, android

I am using an API to get payment info as below, the problem is I can't get values from the variable customParams.

```
 @Override
    public void paymentOperationSuccess(String trxID, Object customParams) {
          Log.d("TAG", "paymentOperationSuccess: " + customParams + " trxid , " + trxID);
    }
```

logcat shows:

```
TAG: paymentOperationSuccess: Bundle[{request_result=200, trx_id=958436921, expiry_date_key=1602970468156, custom_param=null}] trxid , 958436921
```

Comment: that whole "Bundle[....]" block IS the toString() result of them customParams variable... note that it also seems to contain a member called custom_param (no plural) whose value is null.

Comment: @billjamesdev I know but I tried to get it in bundle to get separate every value but I get null bundle

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after casting the Object to Bundle as below:

```
Bundle bundle = (Bundle) customParams;
```